# Cannot Connect to Localhost on worker node

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cluster-computing

I am having some issues connecting to the localhost from one of the worker nodes on my compute cluster. I am running a Spark process using the HDFS file system and so hadoop is also running on the cluster. The cluster utilizes the SLURM job scheduler for parallel processing and so I am trying to submit a SLURM job that calls on Spark and Hadoop but I am getting an extended error message which I have saved to a file and attached.

`Call From greg-n1/172.16.1.2 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

I have also attached the file that I am submitting to SLURM(the header contains some specifications specific to SLURM). I believe the problem may lie in the fact that I am locally calling hadoop/spark(It is only installed in my directory on the cluster).
[image: Program]
[image: Error Output]
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just wanted to add that both spark and hadoop are running ONLY locally and not throughout the cluster.

Comment: You need to look at the core-site.xml to figure out why localhost is being used for the connection string

Comment: Would you like me to show the configurations of the core-site.xml file?

Comment: You already have that file. Did you change it, or just leave the defaults? Can you show it?

Comment: The core-site.xml file for hadoop has "<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>"

Comment: Okay, so what happens when you change that to actually point at a proper IP or hostname for where the namenode runs? And repeat the same for all other nodes

Comment: 9000 seems to the be the default service port. Where would I set the configurations for each individual node(i.e. Namenode - 50070 Datanodes-50075 Secondary name node- 50090)? Thanks for the help, I am very new to this.

Comment: `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` ... If you already have a functional Hadoop cluster, you should already have these files on those servers, and you can copy them to the Kafka Connect workers

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "change that to actually point at a proper IP or hostname for where the namenode runs"?

Comment: Would adding something like this "  <property>
    <name>dfs.https.port</name>
    <value>50470</value>
 <description>The https port where namenode binds</description>

  </property>
" to the hdfs-site.xml file set configurations for the namenode?

Comment: Additionally, I stopped my hadoop daemons but "jps" still brings up a running namenode and sparksubmit programs. Could this be the source of the issue?

Comment: You only need to change fs.default.name, and it needs to point at the machine running the namenode (external host and port), and not localhost (read the wiki link in the error). I'm not able to tell you which value it actually needs to be because [I'm not in your network](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/YourNetworkYourProblem) ... JPS should show a namenode on one machine, and datanodes on others

Comment: The machine running the namenode seems to be the localhost though?(At least that  is where the localhost is being started on as shown above). Do you have any ideas what the external host should be?

Comment: If the namenode is `greg-n1` with ip of `172.16.1.2`, then you should update the xml to say one of those, and not localhost. If the namenode process is not running on port 9000, then change that too. If that isn't the case, then again, I recommend visiting the link in the error message and going through the debugging list